# Scroll to Top Not Taking Effect

Tags: javascript, html, page-jump

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js</script>    

<script>
$(function() {
    $('a.scrollToTop, a[href=#top]').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500);
    return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

and this code within the body:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<p><a href="#top">Back to the Top</a></p>
```

but it's not working. Anybody know why this is? I've looked around but can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in your console, are there any errors? The code you've given is fine so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.scrollToTop, a[href=#top]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

You need to change `})` to `});` after the line with `return false;`. And, since you're looking for the click of an `<a>`, use `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Added but still doesn't work. When I click on Back to Top the URL changes to http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/iOS7.php#top

Comment: Ha, still doesn't work! Am I missing something really obvious out here?

Comment: That's really weird. I copied the code!! Could there be anything that would make it stop working? As I said, when I click on jump to top the URL changes but nothing happens.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you loading?

Comment: Works, thanks all. It was a CSS issue. I had a page container and the code was top: 0, left: 0, right: 0; bottom: 0! Sorry, stupid error, I hadn't edited that code since I started coding so I forget about it!

Answer (score 0):

add ID to your a tag

```
<p>
    <a href="#top" id="scrollTop">Back to the Top</a>
</p>



$('#scrollTop').click(function(){ 
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers already but i had started so here is a fiddle using an id

http://jsfiddle.net/LRtXj/

```
$(function() {
    $("#top").click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 1500);
        return false;
    })
});

 <p><a href="#" id="top">Back to the Top</a></p>
```

Comment: So weird. Nothing is working. I'm using Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: hmmm try in safari and see if that works. i'm on a pc running firefox and it works. tested in chrome too. Are there any javascript errors?